# Can't get all the information when I print two categories together

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written some code in python to scrape some movie names and some additional information related to those movies. What I have written for far is doing fine if I consider printing the two items separately, as in `print(movie)` located in the
middle portion in my script and `print(addinfo)` located at the bottom.

However, when I try to print both of them together at the bottom then I get only the movie names which have additional information as well (the addition information are retrieved from links attached to each movie name. The problem is most of the movie names do not contain the extra link.)

For example, If there are 5 movie names out of which only three have additional links then when I print them together, I get the three movie names and the additional information whereas I am supposed to get 5 movie names printed. I expect to print those names which doesn't have extra information. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance. I think the site address and html information is irrelevant as the code is working well. However, I'm pasting the full code for your consideration.

Script I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

URL = "https://in.bookmyshow.com/vizag/movies"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".card-container"):
    movie = item.select_one(".__movie-name").text.strip()

    print(movie)  ####I do not wish to print it here. I expect to print both (movie and addinfo) together

    blink = item.select_one(".book-button a")
    if blink:
        req = requests.get(urljoin(URL,blink['href']))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        addinfo = ' '.join([item.select_one(".__venue-name").text.strip() for item in soup.select(".listing-info")])

        print(movie,addinfo) ####if i print both of them together then I only get those movies which have items informations as well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

URL = "https://in.bookmyshow.com/vizag/movies"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select(".card-container"):
    addinfo = ''
    movie = item.select_one(".__movie-name").text.strip()
    blink = item.select_one(".book-button a")
    if blink:
        req = requests.get(urljoin(URL,blink['href']))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        addinfo = ' '.join([item.select_one(".__venue-name").text.strip() for item in soup.select(".listing-info")])
    print(movie, addinfo)
```

Output:

```
Tholi Prema Gokul A/C DTS: Vizag
Howrah Bridge INOX: CMR Central, Maddilapalem INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road INOX: Vizag Chitralaya Mall Satyam A/C Dts: Gopalapatnam V Max: Vizag
Chalo Ganesh A/C Dts: Tagarapuvalasa INOX: CMR Central, Maddilapalem INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road INOX: Vizag Chitralaya Mall Mukta A2 Cinemas: Vizag Central, Vizag Mohini Mini: Gajuwaka Mohini 70mm Dolby Atmos: Gajuwaka Narasimha a/c Dts: Gopalapatnam Sri Lakshmi Narasimha Picture Palace: Vizag Sri Venkateshwara Screen 1: Vizag Sarat Theater - 4K Dolby Atmos: Vizag
Touch Chesi Chudu INOX: CMR Central, Maddilapalem INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road INOX: Vizag Chitralaya Mall Mukta A2 Cinemas: Vizag Central, Vizag Raja Cine Max 2K  A/c Dts: Kothavalasa Sharada 4K: Vizag Sri Rama Picture Palace: Vizag Tata Picture Palace A/c Dts: Tagarapuvalasa V Max: Vizag
Bhaagamathie INOX: CMR Central, Maddilapalem INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road INOX: Vizag Chitralaya Mall Jagadamba 4k: Vizag Kinnera Cinema: Maddilapalem Mukta A2 Cinemas: Vizag Central, Vizag Sri Ramulamma Theatre, Thagarapuvalasa: Vizag Sri Lakshmi Narasimha Picture Palace: Vizag Shankara A/C Dts: Gopalapatnam Sri Jaya A/c Dts: Kothavalasa
Padmaavat 
Gang Gokul A/C DTS: Vizag Sri Parameswari Picture Palace: Kancharapalem
Jai Simha Mourya Theatre: Gopalapatnam Sree Leela Mahal: Vizag Saptagiri Theatre: Chittivalasa
Maze Runner: The Death Cure INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road INOX: Vizag Chitralaya Mall Ramadevi 4K: Vizag
Jumanji: Welcome To The Jungle INOX: Vizag Chitralaya Mall
Hey Jude INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road
Green Apple 
Sollividava 
Tagaru 
Savarakathi 
KEE 
Prema Baraha 
Befaam 
Shadow 
Rosapoo 
Aapla Manus 
Kalakalappu 2 
Kumari 21 F 
Karu 
Kirrak Party 
Gayatri 
Inttelligent 
KEY 
Downup The Exit 796 
Pad Man 
The Boy and The World 
The 15:17 to Paris 
Leera The Soulmates 
Aiyaary 
Kanam
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ali. If you take a look at the output above, you can see (after `Hey Jude`) all the movies has got the same information filled in  `INOX: Varun Beach, Beach Road` whereas they all are blank. To be clearer: after `Hey Jude`, the movie names doesn't have any additional information. This what I'm struggling with to fix.

Comment: I just updated my answer, I hope this solves the issue for you.

Comment: No way. It did fix. You definitely deserve an upvote. Thanks for the nice fix.

Comment: No Problem @Topto :D

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of `else` block then another approach could be something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

URL = "https://in.bookmyshow.com/vizag/movies"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".card-container"):
    movie = item.select_one(".__movie-name").text.strip()
    blink = item.select_one(".book-button a")

    if blink:
        req = requests.get(urljoin(URL,blink['href']))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        addinfo = ' '.join([item.select_one(".__venue-name").text.strip() for item in soup.select(".listing-info")])

        print(movie,addinfo)
    else:
        print(movie)
```